# Prevent users to edit eachother entries

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a PHP script that allow users to register entries to a database. Entries are autoincremented. What I found out, is that user #A can get an entry from user #B by changing url from edit.php?id=2 to id=1.

Of course I want to prevent that. So my idea: if the user ID field in the mysql entry matches $_SESSION['user_id'] in my php script, editing is allowed.

A user should only be able to edit entries they have posted themselves.

What would be the best and most efficient way to achieve this?

```
<?php $bruker = $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>

<?php }
/*
   EDIT RECORD
*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
        if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
        {
            // get variables from the URL/form
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $elv = htmlentities($_POST['elv'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $vald = htmlentities($_POST['vald'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $art = htmlentities($_POST['art'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $dato = htmlentities($_POST['dato'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $vekt = (int)$_POST['vekt'];
            $lengde = (int)$_POST['lengde'];
            $flue = htmlentities($_POST['flue'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $gjenutsatt = (int)$_POST['gjenutsatt'];
            $kjonn = (int)$_POST['kjonn'];
            $bilde = htmlentities($_POST['bilde'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

            // check that required fields are not empty
            if ($elv == '' || $vald == '' || $art == '' || $dato == '' || $vekt == '' || $kjonn == '')
            {
                // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                $error = 'Du må fylle ut de påkrevde feltene!';
                renderForm($elv, $vald, $art, $dato, $vekt, $lengde, $flue, $gjenutsatt, $kjonn, $bilde, $user, $error, $id);
            }
            else
            {
                // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fisk SET elv = ?, vald = ?, art = ?, dato = ?, vekt = ?, lengde = ?, flue = ?, gjenutsatt = ?, kjonn= ?, bilde = ?, user = ?
                    WHERE id=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssssiisiisii", $elv, $vald, $art, $dato, $vekt, $lengde, $flue, $gjenutsatt, $kjonn, $bilde, $user, $id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error message if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }

                // redirect the user once the form is updated
                header("Location: /");
            }
        }
        // if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
        else
        {
            echo "Error!";
        }
    }
    // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
    else
```

Comment: `select data,you,need from thetable where recordID=$foo AND userID=$currentuser`. If it's not the right user, they can hack the url all they want, they'll never get any record data to edit.

Comment: Also you should avoid using GET fields when you are trying to edit data to prevent ordinary people from messing with input

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your users have unique ID's you can simply add additional `WHERE` clause to your SQL:

> if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fisk SET elv = ?, vald = ?, art =
>   ?, dato = ?, vekt = ?, lengde = ?, flue = ?, gjenutsatt = ?, kjonn= ?,
>   bilde = ?, user = ?
>                       WHERE id=? AND created_user = ?"))

Obviously replace `created_user` with the column you use to store the users ID who created the entry.

That way it will only ever update a row created by the user trying to edit it.

More securely, you could prevent them from ever seeing the page by first querying the created user id of the row in question then checking it against your user id $_SESSION as you suggest - then killing the script or redirecting them before it ever gets to the query.

Comment: I should probably prevent them from seeing the page if they didn't created it in the first place. Otherwise, the form will return with content from other users. So I would add a query near the first if statements?

Comment: right at the top of the page, check their authorised to edit that item - and if not send them away or kill it